# Geneva Server And SQL Store

Tags: wif, adfs, geneva-server

I have heard from some of the microsoft connect blogs that Geneva Server works with AD/LDAP as identity providers. If I have to configure my own custom attribute store in SQL server, with these users not being in AD groups would that be possible.from the blogs what I have seen is that Genevea Server is tightly coupled with AD and if I have to use custom store then I have to write my custom STS by overriding base classes from the Geneva Framework. So my question is is it possible to authenticate a user from the SQL store,(who is not in AD group) visa the Geneva Server Beta 2?

Comment: Does this still mean any user logging in has to have an Active Directory Account? I want my authentication against a SQL store not against AD. Let me know if that is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, a SQL *attribute* store is supported, but SQL *account* store is NOT supported in beta 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. MS has published a guide that shows you how, you can grab it (GenevaServerFederatedCollaboration-SBS-Guide.pdf) from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=57602615-e1ee-4775-8b79-367b7007e178

See the step titled "Using a SQL Server database as an alternative to using Active Directory or AD DS as a data store"

Comment: Does this still mean any user logging in has to have an Active Directory Account? I want my authentication against a SQL store not against AD. Let me know if that is possible??

Comment: @user77501: Strictly speaking the answer should be: No, Geneva Server (now AD FS 2.0) cannot _authenticate_ against something other than AD, but Yes, you can achieve the same effect by having it _redirect to another STS which authenticates_ against something other than AD.  That other STS could be a WIF-based custom STS.