# Using SQL Account Store in Geneva

Tags: sql-server, claims-based-identity, geneva-framework, sts-securitytokenservice, geneva-server

Geneva has me pretty hot and bothered as a potential to solve complicated auth and SSO issues that have been presented to us by our customers. I understand that Geneva supports custom and SQL-based *attribute* stores. However, I need support for custom and SQL-based *account* stores.

Unfortunately, I [can't find any solid confirmation or denial (page 23)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/d/0/7d0b5166-6a8a-418a-addd-95ee9b046994/Introducing_Geneva_Beta1_Whitepaper.pdf) that it will be supported when it is released, except that [it isn't supported in Beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221680/geneva-server-and-sql-store/1229815#1229815). This gives me hope that it will, but I should know better.

**Question**: Can anyone settle this matter definitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that **Geneva Server** is not going to support other account stores that AD, however you can "easily" achieve this using **Geneva Framework**. There are several examples out there that show how you can build a custom sts that uses any kind of user store.

/Klaus

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You wouldn't happen to have any particularly useful article(s) in mind, would you?

Comment: Sure, have a look at the Starter STS on codeplex: http://startersts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Figures, I whine about not finding an answer, and immediately after posting I do.

[No, Geneva will not support SQL account stores](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/d64837cf-76b7-465b-9803-6e765c46dace/); AD only. They are potentially reviewing it for a future release.